# Long stopover in Canada flying from Riyadh to Orlando. Do I need a visa to enter Canada as a Jordanian citizen?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, canada, jordanian-citizens

I'm flying from Riyadh to Orlando, USA (I have USA visa) with stops at Frankfurt International (FRA) and a 19 hours layover in Toronto (Canada) Pearson International Airport (YYZ) with Air Canada.

Do I need a visa to enter Canada for short-term stays, including transit? Do I need to apply for visa to connect through or I will get the visa transit at airport?

I am a Jordanian Citizen with permanent residency in KSA.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Do you plan to leave the airport in Toronto?

Comment: yes if they can i have 19 hours

Comment: Not sure I follow your comment...

Comment: I think he means if they allow him, he'd like to leave the airport because he has 19 hours there.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=JO&AR=SA&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=US&EM=SA&TR=CA&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#) you will require a visa:

> Transit passengers are required to hold a passport or passport
>   replacing document required to enter Canada.
>
> Passport required.
>
> - Passports and/or passport replacing documents must be valid
>     for the intended transit period.
>
> Visa required.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to
>     cover their stay and documents required for their next
>     destination.
>
> Warning:
>
> - Visitors not holding return/onward ticket could be refused
>     entry.

So a transit or a short stay visa for Canada will be required.

Comment: i will get the visa in the airport or should do it before arrival

Comment: No visa on arrival, you have to get it before arrival.

Comment: That is an entirely different question and no you can't get a visa on arrival.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need a visa to visit Canada, then you don't need one to transit through it. A [government of Canada page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp) makes it simple to check your country. I checked Jordan for you, and you would need a visa to visit.

Of those who need a visa to visit, only four countries in the world qualify for [Transit Without Visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp) through Canada:

- Indonesia
- Thailand
- Taiwan
- Philippines

There are further restrictions such as the length of the connection, what airline you're on, and what airport and terminal you're going through, but none of these are relevant since you are not a citizen of one of these four countries.

In addition there is the [China Transit Program](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/ctp/eligibility.asp) which has similar restrictions on airline, terminal, and so on plus you have to leave from particular cities in China. This program isn't relevant to you either but I mention it for completeness.

Bottom line: **you will need a visa**.

I recommend avoiding private party sites for visa information and sticking to government sites like the one I linked to above. They also provide [instructions for getting a transit visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/transit.asp). If the URL does not end `.gc.ca`, you are not on a Government of Canada site.

Comment: plus for China there is the [China Transit Program](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/ctp/eligibility.asp)